# Lone woman & abusive AI traveling to Earth to investigate something

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, spaceship, artificial-intelligence

I’m looking for a story from a sci-fi anthology published in the past 5 to 7 years in which a woman, who is some kind of investigator, is traveling to Earth - which has been long abandoned - on a mission.  She is alone on a small spaceship, and her AI becomes aggressive. She manages to escape and is picked up by another person on the same mission.  When she gets to earth, she discovers there’s some secret thing happening on the surface of Earth.

Comment: I'm sure you can think of more details. https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info has some prompts for you to check out. And don't forget to visit the [tour] to learn how to accept an answer, and to get your badge.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: Thank you both for your helpful suggestions! I’m going to edit my question (once I figure out how!) to include more information.

Comment: So, do you know what sort of secret thing is going on?

Comment: No, it was just discovered that something was happening, then if I remember correctly it somehow ended. May have been part of one of those collections of books that are really just trying to hook you into buying more books.

Comment: @Plxiny Books now employing DLC tactics!

Comment: DLC tactics...?